# How to scroll to the bottom of the page with Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nightwatch.js

I'm using Nightwatch.js to perform e2e testing on my Vue.js application. My application contains long forms, which "hides" the buttons outside of the view while performing the tests.
I looked into many questions that suggests the usage of `getLocationInView`, but the [documentation](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#getLocationInView) clearly says

> Determine an element's location on the screen once it has been scrolled into view

I tried using something like

```
browser
  .url("http://localhost:8080")
  .setValue("@email", "valid4@mail.ca")
  .getLocationInView("#myElement")
  .submit()    //defined elsewhere
  .waitForElementVisible("#error", 3000);
```

This snippet is supposed to click on a button at the bottom of the form, that's what `submit()` does but when I get the error screenshot to find that no scrolling down whatsoever has happened, leading the button to stay out of focus and therefore unclicked!

is there a way to ultimately scroll to the bottom of the page so I can pass the tests without having to change or at least with minimum changes to my original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking a button requires scrolling to that button to bring it on the screen first, but apparently `setValue` will do the scrolling itself. so instead of scrolling then clicking, I set the value of the button in this way:

```
browser
.url("http://localhost:8080")
.setValue("@email", "valid4@mail.ca")
.setValue("@submitButton", " ")  //<---this line
.waitForElementVisible("#error", 3000)
```

this is like setting focus to the element (the button) then hitting the space bar.

This is not of course the best way to do it, but I think it might be a helpful workaround if your form does not have space and enter restricted from submitting/triggering the button.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `submit`, use [elementIdClick](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/elementIdClick.html) .

The documentation says that this method would scroll the element into view. This would click the button to submit the form rather than attempting to submit the form without interacting with the button.

This seems like a more 'authentic' way to test since users would click the button at the button of the form anyways. Otherwise as you know, the test will keep failing since the button is not in view.

EDIT:

Check out this answer as well: [nightwatch.js - scroll until element is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372354/nightwatch-js-scroll-until-element-is-visible#39408069)